# NetSuite: Create browser link to an order

Tags: html, netsuite

When I run a report out of Netsuite I have the option of sending the link to the email recipient.  When clicked the link opens a new tap on user's default browser and they are directed to the report.

The link in the email looks like:

> https://acct00000.app.netsuite.com/app/common/search/searchresults.nl?searchid=17864

Would anyone know the query parameters so that I can create a link to a Sales Order?

I am trying to add links in a web page that redirect to NetSuite.

I access the search bar like this (Uber Search Bar):

```
table += `<td><a title="Search NetSuite" href="https://acct00000.app.netsuite.com/app/common/search/ubersearchresults.nl?quicksearch=T&searchtype=Uber&frame=be&Uber_NAMEtype=KEYWORDSTARTSWITH&Uber_NAME=${salesOrderNumber}" target="_blank">${salesOrderNumber}</a></td>`;
```

Answer (score 1):

For a Sales Order:

```
https://{account number}.app.netsuite.com/app/accounting/transactions/salesord.nl?id={sales order internal id}
```

Not sure what you mean by "NetSuite Search Bar" - could you add more detail?

Comment: I updated my question to reflect how to access the Uber search bar.  That works but I also get other records like item fulfillments and invoices in the Uber Search.  I don't have access to the NetSuite Internal ID for the Sales Order from the report I'm linking...

Comment: Oh, I see.  You can filter the global search results by record type by adding the first few letters of the record type you want followed by a colon, before the search term. So where you have `Uber_NAME=${salesOrderNumber}` you could make it `Uber_NAME=sal:${salesOrderNumber}` or `Uber_NAME=sal%3A${salesOrderNumber}` with the colon encoded.  HTH.

Comment: SPOT ON!  Thanks!!